# How can I extract a base class from a class that is using the DataContractAttribute without introducing a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

I have a settings class which is persisted using DataContract serialization.  Now I want to extract some of the properties to a base class but this changes the order of entries in the generated xml and breaks deserialization.  I found this surprising since all the fields and the class name are the same.  What is the easiest way to read in old files to the new structure?

Edit: Setting the Order doesn't work.  Base class params always come first, followed by derived members.

e.g.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string A { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string B { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
```

This outputs the params in the order `A, B, C`

Now if I make it

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string C { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

The order will be `C, A, B`.  `C` will be first no matter what I put for the order.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the base-first ordering of data members cannot be overridden by the [`[DataMember(Order=xxx)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  You may need to use a [Data Contract Surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or implement `ISerializable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Order in attribute
e.g. [DataMember(Order = 0)]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the order explicit :

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string zebra;
}

[DataContract]
public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string bird;
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string parrot;
    [DataMember]
    public string dog;
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string antelope;
    [DataMember]
    public string cat;
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string albatross;
}
```

See - [MSDN - Data Member Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The code seems to copied from the MSDN. You may want to add a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to my mind is override the members in derived class to maintain the original order. Optionally, use order in derived type as well.
The problem is that you cannot override fields, thus I would try changing them to properties. Making all properties with public get and set methods should make not a difference (although I am not 100% sure in your case).

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string zebra { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public override string zebra { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string bird { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string parrot { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string dog { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string antelope { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cat { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string albatross { get; set; }
}
```